# Change the page margin of a single page inside a pdf using Quarto?

Tags: latex, pandoc, jupyter-lab, xelatex, quarto

I'm using Jupyterlab and quarto to compile a pdf and I want to change the local page margin of a single page in the pdf, say page 3, and the margin in the rest of the pages are the same and are set globally, is there a way to do this?

I understand that in latex you can use `\newgeometry{...}` and `\restoregeometry`, I wonder if I can do similar things here... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add latex code exactly as is in jupyterlab with the cell mode set as `Raw NBConvert` and then render that ipynb file with `quarto render`.

(I am adding an image of the ipynb file to show how this works)

---

[image: ipynb file with latex code]

---

Now render this `ipynb` file

```
quarto render jupyterlab_file.ipynb
```

and the pdf file with desired page specific margin.

---

[image: page specific margin]

---

(Note that, page 3 has a different margin than others and I have used `showframe` package option just to show the margins.)

---